# why isn't this javascript regex split function working?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to split a string by either three or more pound signs or three or more spaces.

I'm using a function that looks like this:

```
     var produktDaten = dataMatch[0].replace(/\x03/g, '').trim().split('/[#\s]/{3,}');  
     console.log(produktDaten + ' is the data');
```

I need to clean the data up a bit, hence the `replace` and `trim`.

The output I'm getting looks like this:

```
##########################################################################MA-KF6###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF7###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF12###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF13###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF14###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF15###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF16###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF19###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808 is the data
```

How is this possible?  Irrespective of the input, shouldn't the pound and multiple spaces be deleted by the split?

Comment: No, because you did not pass a regex. It should be `.split(/[#\s]{3,}/)`. Are you seeking [this output](https://jsfiddle.net/3swu2xv8/)?

Comment: "either three or more pound signs or three or more spaces" then your regex should be `/#{3,}|\s{3,}/`. Your current regex would also split this `"one##  ##two" -> ['one', 'two']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed a string to the `split`, the input string does not contain that string. I think you wanted to use

```
/[#\s]{3,}/
```

like here:

```js
var produktDaten = "##########################################################################MA-KF6###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF7###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF12###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF13###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF14###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF15###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF16###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808###MA-KF19###Beckhoff###EL1808    BECK.EL1808";
console.log(produktDaten.replace(/\x03/g, '').trim().split(/[#\s]{3,}/));
```

This `/[#\s]{3,}/` regex matches 3 or more chars that are either `#` or whitespace.

NOTE: just removing `'` around it won't fix the issue since you are using an unescaped `/` and quantify it. You actually need to quantify the character class, `[#\s]`.